# Why is VSCode Python terminal misinterpreting Python code and executing uncalled functions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I'm running a Conda environment on VSCode and when I Shift-Enter to run main.py , a new Python terminal opens and runs the script, but functions are executing without being called and I'm getting a :

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Despite the indentation being seemingly fine.

```
import math

def h(x):
    if x==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2*math.sin(x)/x - 1
```

The above returns:

```
(base) josh@Joshs-Macbook Coursework1 % source /Users/josh/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) josh@Joshs-Macbook Coursework1 % conda activate base
(base) josh@Joshs-Macbook Coursework1 % /Users/josh/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 12:59:45) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> return 2*math.sin(x)/x - 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>>>
```

Comment: From what I can tell, Shift+Enter just sends the current line or selection to the terminal. Assuming that's the case, either you have to select all your code before using that shortcut, or use the proper shortcut that runs all the code in a file at once.

Comment: you're trying to run only one line  the last one, as Random Davis says select all your code before send to terminal

Comment: To run python code using command line interface use
`python filename.py`

Answer (score 0):

You have executed the command of `Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal` with the shortcut of `Shift+Enter`. You can select the command of `Run Python File in Terminal` which is above it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Shift+Enter` is keybindings for **Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal**, so if you put cursor in the line of `return 2*math.sin(x)/x - 1`, it will throw errors:
[image]

If you want to enter interactive mode then run the function `h(x)`, please

1. type `python` in integrated Termial;
2. import filename. In my case, it's `a.py` so i `import a`;
3. call the function: `a.h(any number)`
4. exit interactive mode;
   [image]

Or you can get result directly by adding `print(h(any number))`, then clicking the triangle button in top right corner to run python file in integrated Terminal. Get the same result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

run the entire code in python as opposed to the last line.

if you want to run entire scripts:

python3 xxxx.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).